# How to avoid double printed statements with an if statement in a while loop

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist, while-loop

I'm new to stackoverflow and wanted to know why my statement keeps on being repeated twice when i introduce an if statement in my while loop @ "if done, type "back"". Secondly, can someone tell me why the ArrayList keeps an empty String at index 0 when i only add one item to the ArrayList? Thanks!

Here is the code:

package com.codewithrichard;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

 //global variables
  boolean appIsStillOn = true;


 ArrayList <String> shoppingList = new ArrayList<>();

 System.out.println("Welcome to your mobile shopping list" + "\n" + "Your options are");
 System.out.println("1) add item to list");
 System.out.println("2) display list and amount of items in it");
 System.out.println("3) quit!");

 while (appIsStillOn) {
     System.out.println("Option (1-4): ");
     int option1 = input.nextInt();
     if (option1 == 1) {
         while (true) {
             System.out.println("item (if done, type \"back\"): ");
             String itemAdded = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();
             if (!itemAdded.equals("back")) {
                 shoppingList.add(itemAdded);
             } else {
                 break;
             }
         }
     }
     else if (option1 ==2){
         System.out.println(shoppingList);
         System.out.println("size of shopping list: "  + shoppingList.size());
     }
     else {
         System.out.println("Can't wait for you to come back!");
         appIsStillOn = false;
     }









 }










}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried to debug? What is not clear in debugger?

Comment: The first time you call `input.nextLine()`, the `Scanner` is consuming the rest of the line where you typed in the `int` menu choice. That first call will return an empty string which becomes the first item in your list.

Answer (score 1):

The **Scanner#nextInt()** method (and many other **next...()** methods) does not consume the newLine character from the Scanner buffer which is produced when the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key is hit. The **Scanner#nextLine()** method will consume it if encountered **after** a **Scanner#nextInt()** method therefore giving the impression that the prompt for input was skipped over.

Also Consider this...

What is to happen if the User accidentally types in an alpha character instead of a menu choice digit? That's right, your application will crash due to a **InputMismatchException**.

You should always carry out some form of validation for User input and if that validation fails, allow the User to make a proper entry. This obviously promotes a more trouble free environment when using your application. Using your current model, here is an example of this:

```
java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

//global variables
boolean appIsStillOn = true;
ArrayList<String> shoppingList = new ArrayList<>();

System.out.println("Welcome to your mobile shopping list.");

while (appIsStillOn) {
    int option1 = 0;
    while (option1 < 1 || option1 > 3) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Your Shopping List options are:");
        System.out.println("  1) Add item to list.");
        System.out.println("  2) Display list and amount of items in it.");
        System.out.println("  3) Quit!");
        System.out.print("Choice (1-3): --> ");
        try{
            option1 = input.nextInt();
            if (option1 < 1 || option1 > 3) {
                throw new java.util.InputMismatchException();
            }
            /* Consume the enter key hit (newline char) in case
               a Scanner#nextLine() prompt is next so that it 
               doesn't get consumed by that method.   */
            input.nextLine(); 
        }
        catch (java.util.InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.err.println("Invalid menu choice supplied! Try again...");
            /* Consume the enter key hit (newline char) in case
               a Scanner#nextLine() prompt is next so that it 
               doesn't get consumed by that method. It is also
               required here in case an exception has bypassed 
               the above 'input.nextLine()' call.*/
            input.nextLine(); // Consume the enter key hit (newline char)
        }
    }

    if (option1 == 1) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Enter the item to add (when done, enter \"back\"): ");
            System.out.print("Item: --> ");
            String itemToAdd = input.nextLine();
            if (itemToAdd.trim().equals("")) {
                System.err.println("Invalid Item String! You must supply something!");
                continue;
            }
            else if (itemToAdd.equalsIgnoreCase("back")) {
                break;
            }
            shoppingList.add(itemToAdd);
        }
    }
    else if (option1 == 2) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(shoppingList);
        System.out.println("Number of Items in shopping list: " + shoppingList.size());
    }
    else {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Bye-Bye - Can't wait for you to come back!");
        appIsStillOn = false;
    }
}
```